# How to unmount a docker volume in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am creating a Docker Image from a base image that in one of its early layers mounts a volume to the current user home folder utilizing the *VOLUME* directive.

This mount leads to some unwanted file removals on my own image once it is run.

**Is there a way to unmount this volume from within the *Dockerfile* of my image?**

Comment: No, you can't. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020785/remove-a-volume-in-a-dockerfile